# Buddypress - Limit Blog Excerpt on Activity Stream

Tags: buddypress

I'm using the following code to limit the number of words that appear on my blog pages.

`function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) { return 32; } add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );`

I need to limit the number of words that appear on the BuddyPress Activity Stream when someone creates a blog post. Currently when someone creates a new blog post, the excerpt appears on the Activity Stream with about 50+ words. I need to limit this to around 32 words.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thx

Comment: Use the BP filter. See `function bp_activity_content_body()` in `buddypress/bp-activity/bp-activity-template.php`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using. The first part limits the text, the second part ensures the thumbnail is present. Thank you shanebp for pointing me in the right direction.

```
function 5_activity_content_body( $content, $activity ) {
$content_length = 42;
if ( 'new_blog_post' == $activity->type ) {
    $images = extractImageFromContent($content);
    $_content = (strlen($content) > $content_length) ? substr($content, 0, $content_length).'...' : $content;
    
    if(!empty($images)) {
        $_content .= implode("", $images);
    }
    return $_content;
}
return $content;} 
add_filter( 'bp_get_activity_content_body', '5_activity_content_body', 10, 2 );
```

This brings the thumbnail back.

```
function extractImageFromContent($html) {
preg_match_all('/<img.*?src=[\'"](.*?)[\'"].*?>/i', $html, $matches);
return ($matches[0]) ? $matches[0] : array(); }
```